# Increase font size in bootstrap form-select

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am working on a html tempalate where I have a drop down list. The problem is the content in the dropdown list appear to have too small fonts. I am using Bootstrap 5 for this project.

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
                {% for item in availablePickup.timeList %}
                    <option>{{item}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I have tried with oin css

```
option {font-size : 14 px;}
```

But it does not increase the font size. Note that it is the content in the drop down list that I need to increase the font size for.

Comment: i tested your code and it works fine. also you can add select{font-size:44px} to increase font size of selected item. did you clear the cache?

Comment: This is strange, it is not working - even if I clear the cache. Can you show a screen dump of the select box from your side?

Comment: Try removing the space between **14** and **px**. Also try adding !important like : **font-size: 14px!important;**

Comment: i added <style>select,option {font-size : 24px;}</style> and it works file. also according to @CristiánOrmazábal comment, remove space between 14 and px